# Algorithm to resize an image proportionally keeping it as close as possible to given dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, image-processing, image-resizing

### Example

`myFunction(400, 300, 50, 100)` => Must return the width and heigth to **resize my 400x300 (1st and 2nd params) image proportionally**. The resized image **must be at minimum 50x100** (3rd and 4th params). It's totally ok to go 52x.. or ..x102 but the "oversize" must be as small as matematically possible to keep the aspect ratio.

### Details

I must write a function (I will use Javascript/Jquery, but let's not worry about the language: I'm interested in the logic) such as this:

`[new_image_width, new_image_height] function(image_width, image_height, reference_width, reference_height)`

This function takes:

- `image_width`: the width of an image
- `image_height`: the height of an image
- `reference_width`: the desidered minimum width of the image (see below)
- `reference_height`: the desidered minimum height of the image (see below)

It returns:

- `new_image_width`: the proportionally resized width of the image (see below)
- `new_image_height`: the proportionally resized height of the image (see below)

The function must calculate **the closest width and height to respective "reference" parameter, without going below, and preserving the aspect ratio**.

My function must not actually resize the image, only return the new integer to resize to.

Note: I'm confortable with code but 1st-grade-level with math. Please show some mercy :-(

Comment: so what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Nothing useful, I'm afraid :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you don't care about rounding errors**

Let

```
ratio = min(image_width / reference_width, image_height / reference_height)
```

and return

```
image_width / ratio
image_height / ratio
```

---

**If you do care about rounding errors**

Find the greatest common divisor `GCD` of `image_width` and `image_height`. The smallest image you can make with the exact same aspect ratio has dimensions

```
image_width' = image_width / GCD
image_height' = image_height / GCD
```

Every larger image with the exact same aspect ratio is an integer multiple of those. So, let

```
ratio_width = ceil(reference_width / image_width')
ratio_height = ceil(reference_heigth / image_heigth')
```

and

```
ratio = max(ratio_width, ratio_height)
```

then your result is

```
ratio * image_width'
ratio * image_height'
```

Comment: The ratio formula is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so try this:

```
function myFunction(image_width, image_height, reference_width, reference_height) {
    var proportion = image_width/image_height;
    if(reference_height*proportion < reference_width){
        return [reference_width, reference_width/proportion];
    } else {
        return [reference_height*proportion,reference_height];
    }
}
```